# Drupal taxonomy module -- too limited in the identification of Tid based on URL?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri

I have installed Path Breadcrumb module. It works well for simple settings, but when I try to make something more complex, I am at a lost. I have configured a path of this kind: `node/125/%brand/%model`

It works correctly for simple cases. But when either the term brand or model contains spaces (%20/), dashes or special characters, it does not work at all. That is because I use Term name for identification of the taxonomy term. If I use Nid, it does not work, as the URL is of the kind: node/125/FabCar/ModelA and not node/125/20/56, for example.

I was suggested some time ago to use Path Alias, and convert a URL of the kind node/125/20/56 in node/125/FabCar/ModelA, but there are thousands of data, they are updated weekly and even daily, and maintaining all the paths is crazy, so I generate the URLs dinamically, showing 404 if the query in the database yields no results.

All this could be solved if I could look for a taxonomy term by another field, let's say "description", and there I could write the URL-friendly path of the taxonomy. In that way node/125/FabCar/ModelA could be unambigously identified. The name of the term could be Fabricated Car Ltd., and the "description" or another field "FabCar", and I could use this field for the URL path.

How can I circumvent this limitation?